# How to render downloadable file wihich is on localhost:8080

Tags: grails, groovy

This is my code on grails project, i want to create csv file and send the link for downloadable by this link?

When i want to open this link it does not work.

My project is running on `localhost:8080/projectname/`

And my link will be like :  `localhost:8080/projectname/Abc/grails-app/QueryStringCSVFiles/test.csv`

```
def db = new Sql(dataSource)
def result = db.rows("SELECT id,holderName,reportedCountry FROM Claims")

def out = new File('../Abc/grails-app/QueryStringCSVFiles/test.csv') 
def out1 = new File('../Abc/grails-app/QueryStringCSVFiles/test1.csv')

def row1 = ["ID", "HolderName","ReportedCountry"]
out.append row1.join(',')
out.append '\n'

out1.append row1.join(',')
out1.append '\n'

result.each {
    def row = [it.id, it.holderName,it.reportedCountry]
    out.append row.join(',')
    out.append '\n'
    out1.append row.join(',')
    out1.append '\n'
}

def link = [
    link1: "http://localhost:8080/projectname/Abc/grails-app/QueryStringCSVFiles/test.csv",
    link2: "http://localhost:8080/projectname/Abc/grails-app/QueryStringCSVFiles/test1.csv"
]

def links = [link:[link]]
render links as JSON
```

Comment: Where is the `Java`? Define "does not work".

Comment: You can not write into the filesystem and expect grails to pick them up there for delivery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have done it.

-- Build Config

```
...
...

plugins {
  ...
  ...
  compile ":csv:0.3.1"
  ...
  ...
}
```

-- Controller

```
def downloadFile() {
  def data = buildReport()

    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myReport.csv")
    response.contentType = "text/csv"
    def out = response.outputStream
    out.withWriter { writer ->
        def csvWriter = new CSVWriter(writer)

        data.each {
            csvWriter.writeNext(it)
        }

        csvWriter.flush()
    }

}

def buildReport() {
    def claims = Claims.list()
        def report = []

        def headerRow = new String[3]

        headerRow[0] = 'ID'
        headerRow[1] = 'Holder'
        headerRow[2] = 'Country'

        report << headerRow

        claims.each {
            def dataRow = new String[3]
            dataRow[0] = it.id
            dataRow[1] = it.holderName
            dataRow[2] = it.reportedCountry         
            report << dataRow
        }

        return report
}
```